# How can I get a line number for "Unexpected syntax error: Unexpected token c"?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, cross-browser, line-numbers

I'm working on a page and getting "Unexpected syntax error: Unexpected token c" attributed to line 1 of an empty index.

I want to double check that JSON values are valid, but what is the best way to get to the bottom of a line number for "there is a syntax error somewhere in your code, but I'm not telling where?" An approximation of a binary search, where you disable/enable narrower areas of your code and see if you can point a finger that way?

This may be a question for programmers, but I was wondering in general what to do with an error that Chrome doesn't give a useful line number for.

Comment: Such errors can come from calls to `eval()` or `new Function()` too, or from the JSON parser.

Comment: clicking on the message can often lead to a stack, sometimes hidden as "get" in chrome, and the stack should have recognizable function names you can search for.

Comment: Thanks. I debugged this one by logging every JSON string before parsing it, which turned up the malformed JSON it was crashing on. Now it's happy. Thanks,